# How can I form all possible combinations from n lists

Tags: python, list, subset, combinations, python-itertools

This question is difficult to word in the title, so an example is required:

I have 3 lists:

```
L1 = ["Eagle", "Panther"]

L2 = ["Warrior", "Talon", "Machete"]

L3 = ["Feather", "Raptor", "Hunter", "Piranha"]
```

The lists can be of different sizes.

I want to form **all** subsets `{[a,b,c]}` such that `a` is in `L1`, `b` in `L2`, `c` in `L3`

An example is as follows:

`{["Eagle", "Warrior", "Feather"], ["Eagle", "Warrior", "Raptor"], ["Panther", "Machete", "Feather"]...}`

`["Eagle", "Warrior", "Feather"]` is the same as `["Eagle", "Feather", "Warrior"]`, so order does not matter.

I just need all the subsets.

I saw many posts where I can form a subset of a list, but couldn't find what I am looking for here. I can obviously loop and do it, but was wondering if there is an `itertools` solution

Comment: pretty sure you want permutations in itertools

Comment: itertools.permutations is for one iterable - in the asker's case itertools.product is more appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) is used for this.

```
import itertools

L1 = ["Eagle", "Panther"]

L2 = ["Warrior", "Talon", "Machete"]

L3 = ["Feather", "Raptor", "Hunter", "Piranha"]

for x in itertools.product(L1,L2,L3):
    print(x)
```

**Output**

```
('Eagle', 'Warrior', 'Feather')
('Eagle', 'Warrior', 'Raptor')
('Eagle', 'Warrior', 'Hunter')
('Eagle', 'Warrior', 'Piranha')
('Eagle', 'Talon', 'Feather')
('Eagle', 'Talon', 'Raptor')
('Eagle', 'Talon', 'Hunter')
('Eagle', 'Talon', 'Piranha')
('Eagle', 'Machete', 'Feather')
('Eagle', 'Machete', 'Raptor')
('Eagle', 'Machete', 'Hunter')
('Eagle', 'Machete', 'Piranha')
('Panther', 'Warrior', 'Feather')
('Panther', 'Warrior', 'Raptor')
('Panther', 'Warrior', 'Hunter')
('Panther', 'Warrior', 'Piranha')
('Panther', 'Talon', 'Feather')
('Panther', 'Talon', 'Raptor')
('Panther', 'Talon', 'Hunter')
('Panther', 'Talon', 'Piranha')
('Panther', 'Machete', 'Feather')
('Panther', 'Machete', 'Raptor')
('Panther', 'Machete', 'Hunter')
('Panther', 'Machete', 'Piranha')
```

Comment: And, if you want to cover the "order does not matter" requirement, you could create sets out of the tuples returned by `itertools.product`. Just change `print(x)` to `print(set(x))`.

Comment: I know, I wasn't trying to eliminate duplicate tuples, I was just removing the sorted nature of the tuples. The original question stated that he wanted `{[a,b,c]}` back, not `(a,b,c)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
import itertools
L1=["Eagle","Panter"]
L2=["Warrior","Talon","Machete"]
L3=["Feather","Raptor","Hunter","Piranha"]
res=set()
for i in itertools.product(L1,L2,L3):
    res.add(tuple(sorted(i)))
print(res)
```